# Kotlin UninitializedPropertyAccessException when trying to extract current spinner item

Tags: java, android, kotlin, exception, spinner

I have two spinners, the second one changes the array of items it contains based on the value of the first. I need the current item of the second spinner in another class (later on I will probably also need the current item of the first spinner in another class, but for now I'm only trying to get the second one), so I'm trying to save it in a variable.

I globally declared

```
private lateinit var instrumentSpinner : Spinner
private lateinit var tuningSpinner : Spinner
internal lateinit var curTuning : String
```

Here is the logcat:

```
kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property curTuning has not been initialized
        at com.example.tuner.MainActivity.getCurTuning$app_debug(MainActivity.kt:31)
        at com.example.tuner.PitchProcessing.tuneGuitar(PitchProcessing.kt:16)
        at com.example.tuner.MainActivity$onCreate$pdh$1$1.run(MainActivity.kt:130)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Unknown Source:2)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Unknown Source:4)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Unknown Source:208)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(Unknown Source:107)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Unknown Source:11)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(Unknown Source:274)
```

Line 31 is the declaration of that variable (curTuning), line 16 in PitchProcessing tries to use that variable with `MainActivity().curTuning` and in line 130 I call PitchProcessing.

Here are my two spinners in my onCreate:

```
        // initializing instrument spinner
        instrumentSpinner = findViewById(R.id.instrument_spinner)
        ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this,
            R.array.instruments_array,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item
        ).also { adapter ->
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
            instrumentSpinner.adapter = adapter
        }
        instrumentSpinner.onItemSelectedListener = object : OnItemSelectedListener {
            override fun onItemSelected(
                parent: AdapterView<*>,
                view: View?, pos: Int, id: Long
            ) {
                when (parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString()) {
                    "Guitar" -> ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                        this@MainActivity,
                        R.array.tuning_array_guitar,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item
                    ).also { adapter ->
                        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
                        tuningSpinner.adapter = adapter
                    }
                    "Bass" -> ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                        this@MainActivity,
                        R.array.tuning_array_bass,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item
                    ).also { adapter ->
                        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
                        tuningSpinner.adapter = adapter
                    }
                    "Ukulele" -> ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                        this@MainActivity,
                        R.array.tuning_array_ukulele,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item
                    ).also { adapter ->
                        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
                        tuningSpinner.adapter = adapter
                    }
                }
            }
            override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {
                // Do nothing.
            }
        }

        // initializing tuning spinner
        tuningSpinner = findViewById(R.id.tuning_spinner)
        ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this,
            R.array.tuning_array_guitar,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item
        ).also { adapter ->
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
            tuningSpinner.adapter = adapter
        }
        tuningSpinner.onItemSelectedListener = object : OnItemSelectedListener {
            override fun onItemSelected(
                parent: AdapterView<*>,
                view: View?, pos: Int, id: Long
            ) {
                curTuning = tuningSpinner.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString()
            }
            override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {
                // Do nothing.
            }
        }
```

Could someone help me resolve this problem? I tried to figure it out for quite a few hours now, so any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Assigning `curTuning` with null instead got rid of the exception but does not solve the problem itself. However using curTuning like this

```
 object CurTuning {
    var curTuning : String? = null
 }
```

works with the rest of my code (if I adress curTuning with `CurTuning.curTuning` that is)

Edit: It was pointed out that this is redundant and I can just put curTuning into my class directly, however this does not work in my case. But I noticed that when using a companion object, I don't need the variable to be nullable.

Comment: Doing this way might work but that's unnecessary. You're creating a single instance(companion object) of **CurTuning** which is having a nullable var **curTuning**.. This is redudant code, the same thing can be done in the class itself without creating the companion object.

Comment: Can you explain why this works then instead of just directly doing `var curTuning : String? = null` ? I don't know why the companion object works and doing it directly doesn't, but that's how I got the desired behaviour

Comment: Object in kotlin is a **singleton** which is equivalent to **static in Java**. Companion objects are used inside class to put variables and method that should be static(have same value or signature for all instances of the class).  In your case, you have set **var curTuning to null** in a companion object which is reduandant. When referring  ```CurTuning.curTuning```, you're actually referring to the variable inside the **companion object** which have been set to null and now updating it. The same nullable signature works inside the class without using the companion object.

Comment: When not using the companion object, referring to the nullable variable always gives me null though regardless of user choice, but within the companion object I do get the current user choice. However I just noticed that when using the companion object I don't need to make the variable nullable for it to work

Comment: You have to  handle **null check** when you use a nullable variable. If making a variable **lateinit**, you have to **initialize it first**, if you want to avoid ```both nullable and lateinit```, then make your variable **var** instead of **val**. With **var** you can change the variable reference. This is what you're currently doing in companion object. This can be done in the class itself. ```var curTuning:String ="Initial String value"``` and later at some point of time ```curTuning = "new Updated String value"``` since the type is **String**.

Answer (score 0):

When using **lateinit**, you have a boundation of initializing the **lateinit variable before using it else this exception**.

The exception **kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property curTuning** says you're trying to access the **curTuning** variable before initializing it hence the exception has been thrown.

If you're not sure what to initialize **curTuning** with, then make it a **nullable** variable, but make sure to **update and set it with appropriate value and handle nullabillity** else there will **NullPointerException**

Comment: I was under the impression that I did initialize curTuning before using it, since I only use it on the method call in line 130 - making it nullable works, I am guessing spinner does not automatically initialize the first item?

Comment: From your code, what I understood is you're trying to initialize **curTuning** at line 130 inside **tuningSpinner.onItemSelectedListener**. Doing this way wont work as when your app starts it still finds an **uninitialized property** which happens to be the **curTuning** variable and a result throws the **exception** and your app crashes. Either you have to make it **nullable** or set some value to **curTuning** in **onCreate** and later update it.